# buildozer for android cant build my app

Tags: android, python, kivy

I build my app to apk before, but sience few days I can't do build or update for android.
 My `.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android` is empty, but I don't know if it's a reason? It looks like any command can't work for android, for example: 
buildozer android release gives me:

```
...
id: 3 or "android-19"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.4.2
           Revision 3
----------
id: 4 or "android-18"
     Type: Platform
     Desc: Android SDK Platform 4.3
           Revision 2
...
----------
id: 55 or "extra-google-play_licensing"
     Type: Extra
     Desc: Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
           By Google Inc.
           Google Play Licensing client library
           Install path: extras/google/play_licensing
----------
id: 56 or "extra-google-webdriver"
     Type: Extra
     Desc: Google Web Driver, revision 2
           By Google Inc.
           WebDriver
           Install path: extras/google/webdriver

# Android packages installation done.
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/t/py/other/foodapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
/bin/sh: 1: ./distribute.sh: not found
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -l
```

Comment: Did you try to install buildozer again ?

Comment: There is currently a problem with buildozer and Android SDK tools version 20. A possible resolution is available at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kivy-users/K644j5kZg7A/ViERheU8KloJ

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
    buildozer android update
```

I was having some issues with it building the apk, but after running the clean and then update it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have two solutions for your problem:

1. Just remove the **.buildozer/** folder in your project and try again
2. Run the command: buildozer clean